# What is a 8, 4, 2 and 1k texture?

Tags: rendering, texturing, gpu

I read about this for GPU computation and limitation. I don't know what it is...

Answer (score 3):

Those are the sizes of the textures

1K=1024x1024px

2K=2048x2048px

4k=4096x4096px

8K=8192x8192px

Answer (score 2):

- the *K* stands for kilo, meaning 1000x
- the number stands for approximate **horizontal** resolution in pixels

So 4K means roughly 4000px wide image. This also means `2048 × 858`, `2048 x 1024` or
`2048 x 2048` are all 2K resolutions.

Textures usually have 1:1 square ratio, but that isn't a rule. For example an HDRi texture for [equirectangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) mapping will have 2:1 ratio with 8K refering to `8192 x 4096`.

In contrast resolutions like 1080p, 1440p, etc. refer to the **vertical** pixel count.